# DDD referencing child of aggregate root?

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn DDD. I am modeling a property management domain and I think I have two contexts (subdomains?): a property management context and a resident context.

Let's say I have an aggregate root `Apartment`, that holds `Floorplan`s and `Unit`s. Each `Apartment` can have many `Floorplans`, and each `Floorplan` can have many `Unit`s.

```
public class Apartment : IAggregateRoot // for clarity
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Floorplan> Floorplans { get; set; }
}

public class Floorplan
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Bedrooms { get; set; }
    public int Bathrooms { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int FloorplanId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say in the property management context I now introduce a `Resident` who gets assigned to a `Unit`. My `Unit` and `Resident` class now looks like this:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int FloorplanId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resident> Residents { get; set; }
}

public class Resident // in the property management context
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void UpdateBalance(...);
}
```

My question is now if I introduce a `Resident` in the resident context (that can `PayRent()` or `UpdateProfile()`, etc) they must be have a 1:1 relationship with `Resident` in the property management context, but I thought I cannot reference a non-aggregate root entity without going all the way through `Apartment` because a Resident cannot exist without an Apartment.

Is my understanding of aggregate roots incorrect? Is Resident an aggregate root in both contexts? I'm not sure how that would be modeled.

Comment: Well, what does "1:1" mean, in practice? What's the usage pattern? Is this the same user editing something about the Resident in one screen, that later on goes to a different view, and this view needs to reflect the change? Is it two remote users accessing different parts of the application at the same time, each with its own representation of the Resident, but the two affect each other? Must they be synchronized ASAP, or not? Are these (really or effectively) two different applications? Is there a central data store, or more then one? Model  your aggregates to support the usage patterns.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I understand where you are coming from. I really do. But I suspect you are capable of filing in the blanks here. Many of the questions you are asking are not _strictly_ relevant to provide guidance to a general modeling question like the one above. It is not and should not be a requirement that every poster outline their entire architecture in order to receive answers about domain modeling. Please apply the principal of charity as generously as possible when attempting to understand questions. The first 6 words of this post are "I am trying to learn DDD".

Comment: "Many of the questions you are asking are not *strictly* relevant to provide guidance to a general modeling question like the one above" - actually, they are. (Also, I didn't expect for you to explain the entire system - they are meant to be questions that you should ask yourself when designing. Explore those topics in your domain and let what you learn guide you.) How you design your aggregates and whether or not to pursue the ideas you're currently considering depends entirely on these considerations.

Comment: You don't create good aggregates by mechanistically following a set of rules - you put them into your design so that they can solve a problem for you (limit dependencies, make a group of collaborating objects cohesive, enforce invariants, enable specific usage patterns, control the complexity of storing and reconstituting objects, etc.).

Comment: E.g., your `Apartment` class (as presented in your question) is not acting like an aggregate root - in that it's just a tree of objects, and that's not the same thing; it doesn't encapsulate what's within the aggregate, and it doesn't provide an interface to support operations on the aggregate. So it's not a DDD aggregate, even though it's designated as one, which makes other considerations superfluous, because they don't really give you any benefits if you don't have a proper aggregate root.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović You have missed my point. I worry that the above project _is never going to be_ more than a directory containing some files on the user's local machine. That there _is never going to be_ a "view", or an "architecture", or even an "application". I worry that the poster is simply trying to expose themselves to domain modeling in order to grapple with _design_ concepts. And questions that ask them to think about "data stores" and "synchronization" and "architecture" only distract from and obfuscate the problems at hand.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović In fact, I would go so far as to say that it would be a _good_ thing for the poster to ignore many of these concerns to the point that they start becoming a problem. One of the best ways to learn something is to screw it all up so you truly understand the costs. I could be wrong! This _could_ be a project intended for commercial use - where many of the questions you asked above _are_ relevant. But I sincerely doubt it. The OP didn't ask about any of those concerns, so it's better to just leave it at that and answer the questions asked.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović  Your example answer above is great! It points out, correctly, that an aggregate should be a consistency boundary, not just the top of some tree (and you didn't need any information about the architecture to spot that!)

Answer (score 3):

The most critical piece of information a practitioner of DDD needs to understand and, frankly, the biggest stumbling block I see here in this tag, is that DDD is about modeling the *functional* requirements of a system. That is, DDD asks us to take a perspective that focuses on the *behaviors* of our system and let the data that supports these behaviors become an implementation detail.

In your question above I see lots of "this *has* that", and not a lot of "this *does* that". I don't mean to say that your model is necessarily incorrect, rather, that you are *approaching* your system in a way that leads to exactly the problem you have outlined above. When you only focus on the data within a system (I'm guessing your domain model closely resembles your physical model) it almost always leads to "overlapping" concerns.

In this case we should partition our `Resident` *vertically* according to behavior (though sharing an `ID`). Ask yourself, Why does `Resident` in the Property Management Context need to have `FirstName` and `LastName` fields? Are these pieces of data consequential in terms of the use cases present within the context? Does `UpdateBalance` or `RentUnit` require a name? Probably not. On the other hand, the `Resident` in your Resident Context does need these fields if it is to be made responsible for updating this information.

And to be clear, a `Resident` (that is an entity with `FirstName` and `LastName` fields) can *absolutely* exist without an apartment. I'm sitting right here. Always be on the lookout for artificial constraints. I may not be renting from you (yet!), but that shouldn't prevent your system from knowing of my existence. Maybe `Person` or `Customer` is a better name than `Resident` in this case (as the latter carries an implication with it).

To summarize, your model requires two entities (`Person` and `Resident`) in two contexts (Resident and Property Management) that share an identifier from your persistent data store - each responsible for carrying-out and enforcing the particular behaviors relevant to their existence (updating different fields). Whether these map to the same physical database table is an implementation detail.